# How to pass values between classes in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am currently stuck on figuring out why my values aren't passing in xcode. My code looks correct but for some reason it's not passing.

Here is what TheView.h looks like

```
//View Header File
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface TheView : UIView
@property NSString *dateTimeString;
@end
```

and TheView.m

```
// m file of View
#import "TheView.h"
@implementation TheView

// Display method here with dateTimeString in parems
[DrawCanvas dateText: self.dateTimeString];

@end
```

In my controller .h file, I have this code

```
// Controller File
#import "TheView.h"

@interface MainViewController: UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TheView *rootView;

@end
```

MainViewController .m file

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "TheView.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
@property (string, nonatomic) NSTimer *currentTime;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

-(void)updateTime
{
  // prints date successfully
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  NSLocale time = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
  dateFormatter.locale = time;
  formatString = [NSDATEFORMATTER dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE, hh:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];
  NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

  // Current issue is that it isn't passed from here to TheView.m
  [_rootView setdateTimeString:resultString];
}
```

From what I understand in the debug, the string from controller is giving the result I need but it's just not setting the value.

If it helps this code is called viewWillAppear so it will call the updateTime method and won't be nil in theory.

Comment: How is a value assigned to `_rootView`?  Most likely it is `nil`

Comment: The my knowledge the value is assigned to _rootView from the setter getting the resultString and passing it over to the view. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Turns out that I didn't hook it up on the storyboard and that's why it wasn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It looks like `DisplayView` is declared in `TheView.h`. `DisplayView` should be declared in `DisplayView.h` & `DisplayView.m`
2. when you want to set the value just say `_rootview.dateTimeString = resultString;`
3. Set a break point and check for a nil `resultString` when it's being set.

Comment: Hey I don't really understand by what you mean on 1. Can you please explain it to me? I updated the code because I saw something that didn't look right I updated the displayViewController to another name because I didn't know it was a keyword. My bad

Comment: Right now the class of rootView is DisplayView but dateTimeString belongs to your class “TheView”. It’s a class miss match.

Comment: I think I fixed it in the edit. Does it seem right or am I still missing something?